# Windows performance recorder Error while collecting heap snapshot. Error code: 0x80070032

Tags: windows, wpr

I get following error while collecting heap snapshot:

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit>wpr -singlesnapshot heap 3340
>
>         The request is not supported.
>
>         Error code: 0x80070032
> ```

I get this error only on windows server 2016 OS. Tried with 2 different machines, but got the same error.
I tried this on a windows 10 RS5 machine (with same executable) and it worked.
Does anyone know the reason for this error?

THanks.

Comment: 0x80070032 does indeed means not supported. Which Windows 10 SDK version do you use?

Comment: Windows SDK: 10.0.17134

Comment: does inbox wpr.exe from system32 folder show same error?

Comment: wpr.exe from system32 folder does not recognize "-singlesnapshot"  option.

Comment: and newer SDKs like 18362 also show same error? In this case the option maybe only usable for Windows 10 client SKUs